How to specify maven properies when using mvnd?
I get this error when trying to run mvnd clean install:
[ERROR]   The project com.exmpale:my-project:SP-21.053.00_-SNAPSHOT (/home/username/IdeaProjects/my-project/pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     Non-resolvable import POM: The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.assertj:assertj-bom:pom:3.25.0 (absent): Could not transfer artifact org.assertj:assertj-bom:pom:3.25.0 from/to public (https://nexus-ci.com
/repository/public/): PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target @ line 5739, column 19 -> [Help 2]

I was able to resolve it for maven by adding .mvn/jvm.config in project root:
-Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.ignore.validity.dates=true
-Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.allowall=true
-Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.insecure=true

For mvnd I tried adding these properties to:
settings.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<settings xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <localRepository>/home/username/.m2/repository</localRepository>
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>default</id>
            <properties>
                <maven.wagon.http.ssl.allowall>true</maven.wagon.http.ssl.allowall>
                <maven.wagon.http.ssl.insecure>true</maven.wagon.http.ssl.insecure>
                <maven.wagon.http.ssl.ignore.validity.dates>true</maven.wagon.http.ssl.ignore.validity.dates>
            </properties>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
    <!-- other tags are omitted -->
</settings>

.mvn/maven.config in project root:
-Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.ignore.validity.dates=true
-Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.allowall=true
-Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.insecure=true

.mvnd.properties in jvmArgs property:
mvnd.jvmArgs=-Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.ignore.validity.dates=true -Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.allowall=true -Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.insecure=true

and passing them through terminal:
mvnd clean install -Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.ignore.validity.dates=true -Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.allowall=true -Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.insecure=true

But nothing helped.
mvn --version
Apache Maven 3.8.8 (4c87b05d9aedce574290d1acc98575ed5eb6cd39)
Maven home: /opt/apache-maven-3.8.8
Java version: 1.8.0_282, vendor: AdoptOpenJDK, runtime: /usr/lib/jvm/jdk8u282-b08/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "6.7.1-amd64", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"

mvnd --version
Apache Maven Daemon (mvnd) 1.0.2 linux-amd64 native client (cccc1ec8a5b741c62b29f9fb04d37b1678a029bb)
Terminal: org.jline.terminal.impl.PosixSysTerminal with pty org.jline.terminal.impl.jni.linux.LinuxNativePty
Apache Maven 3.9.9 (8e8579a9e76f7d015ee5ec7bfcdc97d260186937)
Maven home: /home/username/maven-mvnd-1.0.2-linux-amd64/mvn
Java version: 1.8.0_282, vendor: AdoptOpenJDK, runtime: /usr/lib/jvm/jdk8u282-b08/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "6.7.1-amd64", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"


Where have you put them? Please show your setup?

@khmarbaise Thanks for answering, I've updated the question

I wasn't able to resolve the issue, but I found a workaround:

do mvn clean install to download all dependencies required to build the project

do mvnd -nsu -o clean install to run mvnd in offline mode

if you get errors indicating that some dependencies are missing, for example:


[ERROR] dependency: org.mockito:mockito-core:jar:1.9.5 (provided)
[ERROR]     Cannot access public (https://nexus-ci.com/repository/public/) in offline mode and the artifact org.mockito:mockito-core:jar:1.9.5 has not been downloaded from it before.

just download required dependency:
mvn dependency:get -DgroupId=org.mockito -DartifactId=mockito-core -Dversion=1.9.5
and do mvnd -nsu -o clean install again
